# async await in recursive function not working?

Tags: javascript, async-await, sudoku

I made a sudoku solver , which take input from textarea and fill it in a grid then using backtracking solve the grid.
but when i make doDfs function async for slow motion filling in grid dom using async await and

```
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}
async function doDfs(board, row, col, box, x, y) {
  //backtracking algo
 //focus on **** part
  if (board[x][y] === ".") {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      if (isValid(row, col, box, i, x, y)) {
      
        textstri(); //fill the grid dom with current updated input****
      await Sleep(1000);//****
        if (doDfs(board, row, col, box, x, y + 1)) {
          return true;
        }
        
        await Sleep(1000);
        textstri();
       
      }
    }
  } else {
    return doDfs(board, row, col, box, x, y + 1);
  }
  return false;
}
```

It stop in between dont know why...\n
please have a look on recursive **doDfs function.**...,
**textstri()** is just taking 2d board array putting in textarea input and grid DOM
backtrack() is utility function to intialize arrays.....
**getsolved** is callback calling doDfs when clicked on solution button.

here is working my code without async await.->

```js
const textArea = document.getElementById("text-input");
const coordInput = document.getElementById("coord");
const valInput = document.getElementById("val");
const errorMsg = document.getElementById("error");
const ge = document.getElementsByClassName("grid")[0];
const suduin = document.getElementsByClassName("sudoku-input");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  textArea.value =
    "..9..5.1.85.4....2432......1...69.83.9.....6.62.71...9......1945....4.37.4.3..6..";
  fillpuzzle(textArea.value);
});

textArea.addEventListener("input", () => {
  fillpuzzle(textArea.value);
});

function fillpuzzle(data) {
  let len = data.length < 81 ? data.length : 81;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let rowLetter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + Math.floor(i / 9));
    let col = (i % 9) + 1;
    if (!data[i] || data[i] === ".") {
      document.getElementsByClassName(rowLetter + col)[0].innerText = "";
      continue;
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName(rowLetter + col)[0].innerText = data[i];
  }
  return;
}

let bord = new Array(9);
let row = new Array(9);
let col = new Array(9);
let block = new Array(9);
function backtrack() {
  //utility function to initialise above arrays
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    bord[i] = new Array(9);
  }
  let ar = textArea.value.split("");
  // console.log(ar);
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      bord[i][j] = ar[i * 9 + j];
    }
  }
  // next ......
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    row[i] = new Array(9);
    col[i] = new Array(9);
    block[i] = new Array(9);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      if (bord[i][j] != ".") {
        let c = Number(bord[i][j]) - 1;
        row[i][c] = true;
        col[j][c] = true;
        let b = Math.floor(i / 3) * 3 + Math.floor(j / 3);

        block[b][c] = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
function textstri() {
  //2d array to grid in dom
  let as = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      as += bord[i][j];
    }
  }
  textArea.value = as;
  fillpuzzle(textArea.value); // text area input to grid dom
}
function getSolved() {
  backtrack();
  // next part....
  let tellme = doDfs(bord, row, col, block, 0, 0); //if dodfs return true mean ans is possible
  if (tellme) {
    textstri(); //here filling bord to grid dom
  } else {
    alert("Wrong input..");
  }
}
function doDfs(board, row, col, box, x, y) {
  //backtracking algo
  if (x === 8 && y === 9) {
    return true;
  } else if (y === 9) {
    y = 0;
    x += 1;
  }
  if (board[x][y] === ".") {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      if (isValid(row, col, box, i, x, y)) {
        row[x][i - 1] = true;
        col[y][i - 1] = true;
        let b = Math.floor(x / 3) * 3 + Math.floor(y / 3);
        box[b][i - 1] = true;
        board[x][y] = `${i}`;

        if (doDfs(board, row, col, box, x, y + 1)) {
          return true;
        }

        board[x][y] = ".";

        row[x][i - 1] = false;
        col[y][i - 1] = false;
        box[b][i - 1] = false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return doDfs(board, row, col, box, x, y + 1);
  }
  return false;
}
function getAnswer() {
  backtrack();
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (
      row[i].includes(undefined) ||
      col[i].includes(undefined) ||
      block[i].includes(undefined)
    ) {
      alert("sorry wrong Answer...");
      return;
    }
  }
  alert("correct answer..");
}
function isValid2(e) {
  backtrack();
  let cood = coordInput.value;
  let x = cood.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
  let y = cood[1] - 1;
  let i = Number(valInput.value);
  let b = Math.floor(x / 3) * 3 + Math.floor(y / 3);
  if (row[x][i - 1] || col[y][i - 1] || block[b][i - 1]) {
    alert("you cant place...");
    return;
  }

  alert("you can place..");
}
function isValid(row, col, box, i, x, y) {
  if (row[x][i - 1]) {
    return false;
  }
  if (col[y][i - 1]) {
    return false;
  }
  let b = Math.floor(x / 3) * 3 + Math.floor(y / 3); // formula to get the 3x3 box and all 9 elements in it.
  if (box[b][i - 1]) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function inputgrid(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "TD") {
    let numb = prompt("enter");
    e.target.innerText = "";
    e.target.innerText = numb === (null || " ") ? "" : numb;
    let arr = [...suduin];
    textArea.value = "";
    arr.forEach((ele) => {
      textArea.value += ele.textContent === "" ? "." : ele.textContent;
    });
  }
}

ge.addEventListener("click", inputgrid);
document
  .getElementById("solve-button")
  .addEventListener(
    "click",
    getSolved
  ); /****call when click on solution button */
document.getElementById("check-button").addEventListener("click", isValid2);
document.getElementById("sol-button").addEventListener("click", getAnswer);
```

```css
code {
  background: #d0d0d5;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-container {
  max-width: 95%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

#user-stories {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

#error-msg {
  color: red;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#sudoku-grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#sudoku-grid {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}

.grid {
  border: 3px solid;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
td input {
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.yAxisLegend {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.yAxisLegend tr td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 2em;
  height: 1.95em;
}

.xAxisLegend {
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.xAxisLegend tr td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.xAxisLegend tr td:nth-of-type(3n) {
  border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.sudoku-input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.C1,
.C2,
.C3,
.C4,
.C5,
.C6,
.C7,
.C8,
.C9,
.F1,
.F2,
.F3,
.F4,
.F5,
.F6,
.F7,
.F8,
.F9 {
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
}

.A3,
.B3,
.C3,
.D3,
.E3,
.F3,
.G3,
.H3,
.I3,
.A6,
.B6,
.C6,
.D6,
.E6,
.F6,
.G6,
.H6,
.I6 {
  border-right: 3px solid;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .form-container {
    align-self: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sudoku Solver</title>
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="An example for the fCC QA Sudoku Solver project"
    />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      id="favicon"
      rel="icon"
      href="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/universal/favicons/favicon-32x32.png"
      type="image/x-icon"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Sudoku Solver</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-container">
        <form id="solve-form">
          <textarea
            rows="10"
            cols="85"
            id="text-input"
            name="puzzle"
          ></textarea>
          <br />
          <input type="button" value="solution" id="solve-button" />
          <input type="button" value="solve" id="sol-button" />
          <div id="error-msg"></div>
        </form>
        <form id="check-form">
          <p>
            Coordinate (A1):
            <input id="coord" class="checker" type="text" name="coordinate" />
          </p>
          <p>
            Value (1-9):
            <input class="checker" type="text" id="val" name="value" />
          </p>
          <input type="button" id="check-button" value="Check Placement" />
        </form>
        <span id="error"></span>
      </div>

      <div id="sudoku-grid-container">
        <div>
          <table class="yAxisLegend">
            <tr>
              <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>E</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>F</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>G</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>H</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>I</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="sudoku-grid">
          <table class="xAxisLegend">
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>8</td>
              <td>9</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="grid">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="A1 sudoku-input" title="A1"></td>
                <td class="A2 sudoku-input" title="A2"></td>
                <td class="A3 sudoku-input" title="A3"></td>
                <td class="A4 sudoku-input" title="A4"></td>
                <td class="A5 sudoku-input" title="A5"></td>
                <td class="A6 sudoku-input" title="A6"></td>
                <td class="A7 sudoku-input" title="A7"></td>
                <td class="A8 sudoku-input" title="A8"></td>
                <td class="A9 sudoku-input" title="A9"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="B1 sudoku-input" title="B1"></td>
                <td class="B2 sudoku-input" title="B2"></td>
                <td class="B3 sudoku-input" title="B3"></td>
                <td class="B4 sudoku-input" title="B4"></td>
                <td class="B5 sudoku-input" title="B5"></td>
                <td class="B6 sudoku-input" title="B6"></td>
                <td class="B7 sudoku-input" title="B7"></td>
                <td class="B8 sudoku-input" title="B8"></td>
                <td class="B9 sudoku-input" title="B9"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="C1 sudoku-input" title="C1"></td>
                <td class="C2 sudoku-input" title="C2"></td>
                <td class="C3 sudoku-input" title="C3"></td>
                <td class="C4 sudoku-input" title="C4"></td>
                <td class="C5 sudoku-input" title="C5"></td>
                <td class="C6 sudoku-input" title="C6"></td>
                <td class="C7 sudoku-input" title="C7"></td>
                <td class="C8 sudoku-input" title="C8"></td>
                <td class="C9 sudoku-input" title="C9"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="D1 sudoku-input" title="D1"></td>
                <td class="D2 sudoku-input" title="D2"></td>
                <td class="D3 sudoku-input" title="D3"></td>
                <td class="D4 sudoku-input" title="D4"></td>
                <td class="D5 sudoku-input" title="D5"></td>
                <td class="D6 sudoku-input" title="D6"></td>
                <td class="D7 sudoku-input" title="D7"></td>
                <td class="D8 sudoku-input" title="D8"></td>
                <td class="D9 sudoku-input" title="D9"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="E1 sudoku-input" title="E1"></td>
                <td class="E2 sudoku-input" title="E2"></td>
                <td class="E3 sudoku-input" title="E3"></td>
                <td class="E4 sudoku-input" title="E4"></td>
                <td class="E5 sudoku-input" title="E5"></td>
                <td class="E6 sudoku-input" title="E6"></td>
                <td class="E7 sudoku-input" title="E7"></td>
                <td class="E8 sudoku-input" title="E8"></td>
                <td class="E9 sudoku-input" title="E9"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="F1 sudoku-input" title="F1"></td>
                <td class="F2 sudoku-input" title="F2"></td>
                <td class="F3 sudoku-input" title="F3"></td>
                <td class="F4 sudoku-input" title="F4"></td>
                <td class="F5 sudoku-input" title="F5"></td>
                <td class="F6 sudoku-input" title="F6"></td>
                <td class="F7 sudoku-input" title="F7"></td>
                <td class="F8 sudoku-input" title="F8"></td>
                <td class="F9 sudoku-input" title="F9"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="G1 sudoku-input" title="G1"></td>
                <td class="G2 sudoku-input" title="G2"></td>
                <td class="G3 sudoku-input" title="G3"></td>
                <td class="G4 sudoku-input" title="G4"></td>
                <td class="G5 sudoku-input" title="G5"></td>
                <td class="G6 sudoku-input" title="G6"></td>
                <td class="G7 sudoku-input" title="G7"></td>
                <td class="G8 sudoku-input" title="G8"></td>
                <td class="G9 sudoku-input" title="G9"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="H1 sudoku-input" title="H1"></td>
                <td class="H2 sudoku-input" title="H2"></td>
                <td class="H3 sudoku-input" title="H3"></td>
                <td class="H4 sudoku-input" title="H4"></td>
                <td class="H5 sudoku-input" title="H5"></td>
                <td class="H6 sudoku-input" title="H6"></td>
                <td class="H7 sudoku-input" title="H7"></td>
                <td class="H8 sudoku-input" title="H8"></td>
                <td class="H9 sudoku-input" title="H9"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="I1 sudoku-input" title="I1"></td>
                <td class="I2 sudoku-input" title="I2"></td>
                <td class="I3 sudoku-input" title="I3"></td>
                <td class="I4 sudoku-input" title="I4"></td>
                <td class="I5 sudoku-input" title="I5"></td>
                <td class="I6 sudoku-input" title="I6"></td>
                <td class="I7 sudoku-input" title="I7"></td>
                <td class="I8 sudoku-input" title="I8"></td>
                <td class="I9 sudoku-input" title="I9"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: If your `doDfs` function is asynchronous, you will also need to `await` the recursive `doDfs(…)` call

Comment: `if (await doDfs(...))` and `return await doDfs(...)`

Comment: thank you so much it worked .but can you tell me the concept ..so that i can get logic.